# How can I control when a DLL is detached

Tags: c#, c++, dll, import, export

I got a DLL that I want to add to my C# project and I have some problems. First, my DLL is coded in C++ and I got an interface of one function to export it.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* sniff() 
{
    return ps.Sniff();
}
```

I have an instance "ps" that initialise a socket when the DLL is attached. The point is that I need to have this instance initialise when I call my exported function. My problem is when I import it in my C# project, my DLL is detached for no apparent reason and I can no longer call my exported function.

I use this syntax in my C# projet :

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Pat\Bureau\sniffoporn\Release\sniff.dll", EntryPoint = "sniff", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr sniff();
```

Some important things that I tryed :

1. Import the DLL in the reference of the project : Can't because it's not a COM component.
2. Manually import the DLL using LoadLibrary, FreeLibrary and GetProcAddress : Same result
3. Call my exported function in loop : Same thing but the DLL is attached for a little longer before detaching.

I would want to know why my DLL is detaching and how can I keep it attached for the rest of the process life.

Thanks a lot

Comment: `my DLL is detatched for no apparent reason`... are you getting an exception?  Can you post it here?  Not sure what you mean by `detatched`...

Comment: It's not an exception, I just call a MessageBox when the DLL is attach/detach : `case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
  ps.Connect();
  MessageBox( NULL, "p_attach", "IbeTheSee", MB_ICONWARNING );
 case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
  ps.Disconnect();
  MessageBox( NULL, "p_detach", "IbeTheSee", MB_ICONWARNING );`

Comment: How are you determining if its attached or detached?  Can you post the code where you have the MessageBox?

Comment: According to this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx), you will get a DLL_PROCESS_DETACHED event even if the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH returns false.  It might be the case that its not being loaded properly.  I'd comment out all the code in the C++ portion.  If it still fails, then you know its a loading issue.

Comment: It's not a loading problem because I can call my exported function properly for some times. I may have found my problem tho : The fact that I could'nt call my function anymore was not because the DLL was not reachable but because the return value were null. I commented the "ps.Disconnect()" part to see what happens and it occurs that all go well after the DLL is detatched. I must conclude that a DLL that is not attached to the process is not necessarily unreachable. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Interesting path to the dll..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an exception occurs in your DLL itself. Making it detach in Visual Studio to prevent your application from crashing. After all C# is managed code.

Try your same procedures with a different (dummy) dll with very simple functionality. If it still occurs then something with your method is wrong, otherwise with the DLL you are attempting to use.